# Is there any running gear that doesn't require washing and doesn't stink after every use?

Tags: running, long-distance-running, sweat

I want to minimize the time I spend on washing my running gear, and the probelem is always that I have to do a significant amount of laundry because I'm running everyday, and sweating in my gear.
Is there a way to minimize the amount spent doing laundry?
One possiblility is to get some running fabric that doesn't stink no matter how much one sweats in it.
Does any such thing exist?

Comment: Not sure if such a thing exists, but I wear my running clothes into the shower. Then I rinse them off and wring them out. Takes the stink out and gives you one more use out of them.

Comment: I removed the "where can I buy it" part, since this site is specifically NOT for purchase recommendations. But the overall question of what to look for in terms of fabric is a good question.

Comment: From my personal experience, the biggest factor isn't actually the fabric being used, but rather how you handle it afterwards. Especially with heavy sweating, it actually runs pretty clean, so the smell is as much from tossing it into your gym bag wet as anything else. If you hang it, or lay it out flat to dry, it's generally pretty inoffensive, at least until you get it wet again, and at that point, people expect you to smell like you've been sweating in it, so you can at least use the same gear several days in a row..

Comment: Outside of that, there does exist materials that have anti-microbial coatings or weaves (often involving silver nanoparticles). Since much of the smell from running comes from bacteria, that does create workout clothing that needs less washing. Unfortunately, those coatings eventually wear out.

Comment: Buy enough t-shirts and trousers, so you have enough to make a loundry once a week. And literally, any fabric, because it's not the fabrics that smell, but your sweat :)

Comment: You should take a look at merino wool clothing. It has anti bacterial properties so this should reduce sweat smell. Combine this with airing out your clothing by hanging it (preferably outside) instead of throwing it on the ground on a pile and you should be able to wear the same pieces of clothing multiple times.

Comment: @DanubianSailor I have enough t-shirts and trousers, but at the end of the week, my laundry basket smells like an old boxing glove. Probably I need to put it at the balcony.

Comment: I usually hang my post-run shirts/shorts outside and let them bake in direct sunlight during the day. The sunlight seems to break down the stinky better than any detergent (for me anyways)

Comment: I'd second what @DanubianSailor - I bought six sets of identical running clothes and wash them all at the end of the week.  Probably want to choose synthetic fabrics though that wick sweat as it least then your sweat is effective at cooling you down (so you need to sweat less than if you wear cotton t-shirts that just get soaked without cooling you down much).  My running kit tends to be pretty much dry by the time it gets to the laundry basket.

Answer (score 1):

I hang my running clothes to dry freely (not in a cupboard and not in a bag), and can run a few days without the smell being *that* noticeable to myself. As far as I'm concerned, getting them dry is imperative - bacteria need a moist environment to grow; they feed on whatever food they get from your sweat, but only require H2O in some form to multiply. So it is more likely that a completely dry piece of cloth will have less bacteria and hence less smell for a longer time.

Aside from that, there are a few materials that supposedly have antibacterial properties (Merino wool, or synthetics with silvery stuff mixed in); I cannot really say that I had much difference with them.